Debug Laravel App running on Herd with Xdebug
I'm trying to setup debugging for a Laravel app running on my machine (via Herd).
The initial server configuration looks like this:

Then I hit "Start Listening to PHP Debug connections" in PhpStorm and reload the page.
For this URL,

I get this:

After accepting this, the server configurations looks like this:

So, at this point I have debug pointers set up in the controllers and expecting them to be hit. But, when I reload the page I run into this:

Any clues??

Have not worked with Herd myself, so cannot give a direct answer... but try to check the path correctness this way: 1) Make a new endpoint/URL in your app (e.g. /xdebug-test) 2) In a controller/action that will be rendering the output for that endpoint, just print the phpinfo() output. In particular, you are interested in the $_SERVER[] output -- you need to see the "real" project path. 3) Call that URL and see what path is used there and what PhpStorm is using in the debug path mapping. P.S. Also check what __DIR__  / __FILE__ will report in that action (if it will be different).
